# Datagrid displaying and filter for item with multiple tags or groups

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity, angular9

So I'm making a dashboard with Angular 9 and Clarity v2 where different Datagrids are needed. Now some of those Datagrids have data like meeting rooms where name, building and floor are included but those are not the problem, I want to add tags/groups so I can know which room belongs to which groups. So I tried to check the documentation but I didn't see anything about being able to display a list/array of strings, nor did I find any information about how to filter that data.

So this is an example of what I would like to achieve (with a checkbox filter):
[image: Data table with tags]

So far I was able to make the following Datagrid:

```
<clr-datagrid [(clrDgSingleSelected)]="selectedBuilding" [clrDgRowSelection]="true" *ngIf="!isLoading&&!hasError">
    <clr-dg-column [clrDgField]="'name'">
        <ng-container *clrDgHideableColumn="{hidden:false}">Name</ng-container>
    </clr-dg-column>
    <clr-dg-column [clrDgField]="'address'">
        <ng-container *clrDgHideableColumn="{hidden:false}">Address</ng-container>
    </clr-dg-column>
    <clr-dg-column [clrDgField]="'timezone'">
        <ng-container *clrDgHideableColumn="{hidden:false}">Timezone</ng-container>
    </clr-dg-column>
    <clr-dg-column [clrDgField]="'formatAMPM'">
        <ng-container *clrDgHideableColumn="{hidden:false}">Time format</ng-container>
    </clr-dg-column>
    <clr-dg-placeholder>There are no Buildings yet. Let's make one, shall we?
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-no-margin-r" (click)="onNewBuilding()">
            <clr-icon shape="user"></clr-icon> new building
        </button>
    </clr-dg-placeholder>
    <clr-dg-row *clrDgItems="let building of buildings" [clrDgItem]="building">
        <clr-dg-cell>{{building.name}}</clr-dg-cell>
        <clr-dg-cell>{{building.address}}</clr-dg-cell>
        <clr-dg-cell>{{building.timezone}}</clr-dg-cell>
        <clr-dg-cell>{{building.formatAMPM}}</clr-dg-cell>
    </clr-dg-row>
    <clr-dg-footer>
        <clr-dg-pagination #pagination [clrDgPageSize]="10">
            <clr-dg-page-size [clrPageSizeOptions]="[10,20,50,100]">Rooms per page</clr-dg-page-size>
            {{pagination.firstItem + 1}} - {{pagination.lastItem + 1}} of {{pagination.totalItems}} categories
        </clr-dg-pagination>
    </clr-dg-footer>
</clr-datagrid>
```

I hope someone will be able to help me with this issue.
Thanks in advance.

## EDIT 1:

There are 2 questions that I have, first how can I display a list of labels from an array in a datagrid cell?

The second question I have is: Is it possible to create a filter with checkboxes that will show the items that contain the selected label?

I have also made an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-v3-light-theme-svr1sb) of what I have right now. There you can see that the datagrid displays it with a regular "," between items. It does filter it based on what I type, but when typing "2010,2017" or with spaces all data disappears so I would like to do this with checkboxes instead. Also because the user can create, update and delete groups but also apply them to buildings, so I would like to make it so I can retrieve all user groups and add them to the filter. This way the filter is dynamical and multiple tags can be chosen.

## EDIT 2:

Also It would be nice if its possble to click on a label and activate the filter for it.

Comment: Is the main question about how to make a list of labels appear from an array or a problem with the Datagrid? Also Clarity 2 and Angular 9 are incompatible, you should update to Clarity 3 to ensure it works properly. It also helps to have a working example of your full demo to see everything at once https://stackblitz.com/@clr-team has starters.

Comment: It's good to know I have to update to v3 didn't know those were not compatible. I have also created an example and added in the questions I have about this

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your first question about creating a list of labels is to use `*ngFor` to generate a list of labels. This is standard for anything you want to loop over, and should just go inside of the cell.

```html
<span class="label" *ngFor="let group of groups">{{group}}</span>
```

The second question about a custom filter is more complicated, but is documented at https://clarity.design/documentation/datagrid/custom-filtering. There is also a snippet from the demo source here https://github.com/vmware/clarity/blob/master/src/website/src/app/documentation/demos/datagrid/utils/color-filter.ts.